# how to create a text file in unix server using a java code?

Tags: java

I'm new in java. I have done an application and it contains a property file in which log path is configured. It is working fine in windows. This is the method for the same.

```
                  File file = new File(logPath);
                  file.createNewFile();
```

Actually this tool has developed for a third party and they are running in unix os. My question is, this file creation will work in UNIX platform or needs to change the code for that ?

Comment: Yes, this is the promise of Java: "Write once, run anywhere".  It'll work on Windows, Unix, Mac...

Comment: No. You dont need to make any changes.

Comment: You might have to adapt the `logPath`

Comment: I would recommend installing a VM on your development machine and loading it with linux os to actually *try* your app on a *nix os.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no.

If `logpath` is an absolute path, then no. In Windows, this would contain a drive letter and such a path would not be understood by a *nix OS.  This For example would not work:

```
"C:\log.txt"
```

If it is not an absolute path, but a relative one, then it should just work as the other answers state.  For example, this will work:

```
"data\log.txt"
```

Such a file would be saved relative to the running programs working directory, so if you were running this (on *nix) from `/home/user/`, then the file would be created at `/home/user/data/log.txt` (assuming the data folder already existed).

Obviously, this file then moves around depending on where you were when you started the program.

The best solution is to save this data to the user's home directory, which is a common concept on all the platforms you've mentioned:

```
String home = System.getProperty("user.home");

File data_directory = new File(home, ".my_app_data");
data_directory.mkdir();

File log_file = new File(data_directory, "jamie.txt");
try {
    log_file.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle error
}
```

You will notice I am using the `File(string, string)` constructor to build up the path.  This will join the separate parts together using the correct path separator for the platform (i.e. `\` on Windows, `/` on *nix).

Comment: As I said, this would not work, because you have a windows specific `D:\` in there.  That would not even work on many windows machines, as it requires there to *be* a D:, which isn't guaranteed.

Comment: LOG_PATH = d:\\data\\Log. No. This is my configuration file for showing you. It should editable.

Comment: You are going to have the exact same problem in loading your configuration file in the first place, as I assume at some point in your code you've got `"D:\...\config.txt"` or something like that.

Comment: Ok. If i'm running in UNIX, how to set my config file. It is something like LOG_PATH = /mnt/data/log instead of LOG_PATH = D:\\data\\Log. Also using File(string, string) method. Is it right ?

Comment: Please comment to above query.

Comment: You should probably do this: 1. On start, try to load config file from user's home directory 2a. If it exists fine, load your config (including the log file path) 2b. If not, create a default one, containing a log file path create relative to the user's home directory 3. Open the log file from the path used in step 2.

Comment: LOG_PATH = /export/home/normal/log              
LOG_FILE = MyLog.log . this is actually my property file. but log creates as "log\MyLog.log"

Comment: Not sure I follow, what is the full path that the file is created at, and what is the code that creates the final `File` object?

Answer (score 0):

Java is cross-platform by definition. Write once, compile once, run everywhere. Your code will work on all java supported platforms.

Comment: Actually my doubt was, in windows we are directory path like D:\\directoryName\\filename. but in unix it is possible to mount the directory structure as /mnt/directory/../